# Html Agility PacK vs Sharp Query?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, html-agility-pack

I am writting a web application which will require me to purse html files.What I doing is quering for content included in a specific div with in a page. From my research online I came a cross HTML agility pack and Sharp Query. I would like to know which one is better?

ASP.NET MVC 2, .NET 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I prefer SharpQuery as it is based on SgmlReader. Also the CSS3 selectors are really nifty. On the other hand HTML Agility is more portable on platforms such as Silverlight, Windows Phone, ... so if you need this sort of interoperability you should probably choose HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you help me where I can find a nice tutorial for SharpQuery. I am having hard time finding one.

Comment: @EmmanuelN, sharp-query uses CSS3 selectors, which are also used by jQuery. So any tutorial about CSS3 selectors might be helpful.